# Function only works 1 time

Tags: php, file, function, upload

I wrote a script for uploading an image to my server. Users can use it e.g. for uploading their avatars, or their works.

This is the function in functions.php

```
function save_image($image, $uploadedfile)
{

error_reporting(0);

$change="";
$abc="";


 define ("MAX_SIZE","40000");
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 $errors=0;


    if ($image) 
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($image);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {

            $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {

 $size=filesize($uploadedfile);


if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
    $errors=1;
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $uploadedfile;
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $uploadedfile;
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $scr;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


$newwidth=$width;
$newheight=$height;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);


$filename = "images/vcard_images/". $image;



imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
}}


}
```

So now I have a form on the page create.php where they can upload 6 of their works. So they select 6 files from their hard drive and then press save. Then I call the function 6 times like this:

```
$work1 = $_FILES["work1"]["name"];
save_image($_FILES["work1"]["name"], $_FILES['work1']['tmp_name']);

$work2 = $_FILES["work2"]["name"];
save_image($_FILES["work2"]["name"], $_FILES['work2']['tmp_name']);

$work3 = $_FILES["work3"]["name"];
save_image($_FILES["work3"]["name"], $_FILES['work3']['tmp_name']);

$work4 = $_FILES["work4"]["name"];
save_image($_FILES["work4"]["name"], $_FILES['work4']['tmp_name']);

$work5 = $_FILES["work5"]["name"];
save_image($_FILES["work5"]["name"], $_FILES['work5']['tmp_name']);

$work6 = $_FILES["work6"]["name"];
save_image($_FILES["work6"]["name"], $_FILES['work6']['tmp_name']);
```

But the weird part is, if I press SAVE, the page just becomes white. And if I only call the function onces, so only this:

```
$work1 = $_FILES["work1"]["name"];
save_image($_FILES["work1"]["name"], $_FILES['work1']['tmp_name']);
```

It works perfectly fine..

No idea what I'm doing wrong..

Kind regards

EDIT:

Error reporting told me this:

```
Notice: Constant MAX_SIZE already defined in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vcard2/user/functions.php on line 11

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getExtension() (previously declared in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vcard2/user/functions.php:12) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vcard2/user/functions.php on line 12
```

Comment: Seeing your code it only takes 1 picture you have to store the images in an array.

Comment: Do you have enabled your error messages?

Comment: Try enabling [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (with `E_ALL`) and [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), so maybe the "white page" will became more useful.

Comment: you could also check with isset or empty: 
`foreach (range(0,7) as $num) {
  if (!empty($_FILES['work'.$num]['tmp_name'])) {
  save_image($_FILES["work".$num]["name"], $_FILES['work'.$num]['tmp_name']);
  } 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to have a look at HTML5's FILE API, which manages multiple files uploading and Drag and Drop system. two recommended scripts if you want to play around:

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

and

https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop

i tried them both and they are nice

Comment: Thank you! But i really would like to use this script!

Answer (score 2):

You have a typing error: echo $scr instead of echo $src

Comment: Oh yes I see, but this doesn't make it work ofcourse :)
Thanks anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are two seperate but are happening for the same reason:

```
Notice: Constant MAX_SIZE already defined in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vcard2/user/functions.php on line 11
```

You write DEFINE inside your function. The first time it runs it works fine, but the seconds time, it is already defined. Move DEFINE out of the function `save_image`

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getExtension() (previously declared in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vcard2/user/functions.php:12) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vcard2/user/functions.php on line 12
```

The same goes for this error. The seconds time the function runs the function getExtention is redicleared. Move the function outside of `save_image` and it should be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your function contains a `define` statement. This is executed every time you call the function, but `define` fails when you try to re-define an existing constant.

Place this `define` statement outside of the function, instead.

Same story for that function `getExtension`: it's not clear to me why you're doing that inside another function; don't.

Answer (score 0):

Move the function `getExtension` out of the `save_image` function.

Nested functions in PHP are not bound to the "private" scope of the function,
they come into the global function table.
And you can't redclare a (global) function.

If you really want to nest functions, then declare when nondeclared only:

```
if (!function_exists('getExtension')) { function getExtension(){...}}
```

You should consider to move the `define` Statement also out of the function 
or make it conditional :

```
if (!defined('MAX_SIZE')) { define('MAX_SIZE', 1024); }
```

And you could also check the Requestvars with `isset` or `empty`, ie. in a loop:

```
foreach (range(1,7) as $num) { 
  if (!empty($_FILES['work'.$num]['tmp_name'])) { 
    save_image($_FILES["work".$num]["name"], $_FILES['work'.$num]['tmp_name']); 
  } 
}
```